# Alguien podria explicar este comportamiento de julia en el REPL

Tags: julia

```
julia>   a=[11,12,13,14,15]; i=1; @show(a[1:i],a[i+end-1:end], sum(a[(i+end-1):end]))
     a[1:i] = [11]
     a[(i + end) - 1:end] = [15]
     sum(a[(i + end) - 1:end]) = 15
     15
```

==> es CORRECTO, pero al incrementar i:

```
julia> a=[11,12,13,14,15]; i=2; @show(a[1:i],a[i+end-1:end], sum(a[(i+end-1):end]))
a[1:i] = [11, 12]
a[(i + end) - 1:end] = Int64[]
sum(a[(i + end) - 1:end]) = 0
0
```

==> incorrecto, deberia resultar (14+15)  = 29

Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.